# Orthogonal basis of a Cartan of a Lie algebra with respect to Killing form.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I am trying to understand orthogonal basis of a Cartan of a Lie algebra with respect to Killing form.

For example, let $g=sl_2 = \text{Span}\{h, E, F\}$. Then a Cartan of $g$ is $\mathfrak{h} = \text{Span}\{h\}$. By definition, the Killing form is $K(x, y) = tr(ad(x)ad(y))$, $x, y \in g$. Therefore $K(h, h) = tr(ad(h)ad(h))$. We have
$$
[h,h]=0, \\
[h,E]=2E, \\
[h,F]=-2F.
$$ 
Therefore the matrix of $ad(h)$ is
\begin{align}
ad(h) = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 \end{matrix} \right).
\end{align}
Hence $K(h, h) = tr(ad(h)ad(h)) = 8$ and $tr(ad(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}h)ad(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}h))=1$. Therefore the orthonormal basis of the Cartan $\mathfrak{h}$ is $\{ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}h \}$. Is this correct?

Let $g=sl_3 = \text{Span}\{h_1, h_2, E_1, E_2, E_3, F_1, F_2, F_3\}$. Then a Cartan of $g$ is $\mathfrak{h} = \text{Span}\{h_1, h_2\}$. We have $K(h_i, h_j) = tr(ad(h_i)ad(h_j))$. We have
$$
[h_1,h_1]=0, \\
[h_1,h_2]=0, \\
[h_1,E_1]=2E_1, \\
[h_1,E_2]=-E_2, \\
[h_1,E_3]=E_3, \\
[h_1,F_1]=-2F_1, \\
[h_1,F_2]=F_2, \\
[h_1,F_3]=-F_3,
$$ 
$$
[h_2,h_1]=0, \\
[h_2,h_2]=0, \\
[h_2,E_1]=-E_1, \\
[h_2,E_2]=2E_2, \\
[h_2,E_3]=E_3, \\
[h_2,F_1]=F_1, \\
[h_2,F_2]=-2F_2, \\
[h_2,F_3]=-F_3.
$$ 
Hence $K(h_1, h_1) = tr(ad(h_1)ad(h_1)) = 12$ and $K(h_2, h_2) = tr(ad(h_2)ad(h_2)) = 12$. What is the orthogonal basis of $\mathfrak{h}$? Thank you very much.

Edit: we have
\begin{align}
ad(h_1) = diag(0, 0, 2, -1, 1, -2, 1, -1), \\
ad(h_2) = diag(0, 0, -1, 2, 1, 1, -2, -1).
\end{align}
Therefore $K(h_1, h_1) = K(h_2, h_2) = 12$, $K(h_1, h_2) = -6$. Therefore $h_1$ is orthogonal to $h_1 + 2 h_2$. Hence $\{h_1, h_1+2h_2\}$ is an orthogonal basis of $\mathfrak{h}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Why would you want to normalise for the Killing form? The scalar factor involved in the definition of the Killing form is not important, only orthogonality really matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed $h_1$ and $h_2$ have equal lengths, and make an (obtuse) angle of $\frac{2\pi}3$; hence $2h_2+h_1\perp h_1$.